# border-radius: 50% for rounded image crossed out in console

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm following standard procedures for creating a round image in ReactJS.

```
.about-profile {
    display: block;
    width: 260px;
    height: 260px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

<img className="about-profile" src="./images/profile.jpg"/>
```

[image]

Why is `border-radius: 50%` not being applied in this case?

Comment: Crossed out text means it's overwritten somewhere else. Are you sure your element does not have any other CSS applied? Also `border: 1px solid red;' and 'border-left: 2px solid blue;` will cross out `border:` rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the *cascade* in CSS in effect. Some other rule is overriding your border radius.

For more details see https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade

What you can do is either change `.about-profile` to be more "specific", or use `!important` to override the other rules. I suggest the former.

Comment: Thanks. I checked my other rules and don't see anything that might be overriding it. But that was a proper answer! Will upvote in 6 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
border-radius: 50%!important;
```

Answer (score 0):

some style override this code so use !important

```
.about-profile {
  display: block;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```